# TypeError: Discord.MessageEmbed.setDescription is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using discord.js to make a discord bot and i get error "TypeError: Discord.MessageEmbed.setDescription is not a constructor" when the command is used

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'stats',
    description: 'Views the bot\'s stats',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed
        .setDescription(`In ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing
 `const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed`
to
`const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()`